# 'Method is never used' although it is being used- Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, onclick

As it is said, it gives this message although it is being used. It is somehow not being identified.
Here is the `java class`

```
package com.example.exploringlayouts;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);


    }
    void loadConstraintLayout(View v){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    void loadTableLayout(View v){
       // setContentView(R.layout.my_table_layout);
    }
    void loadMenuLayout(View v){
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
    }
}
```

and here part of the `OnClick` segment that involves that method said that is not used.

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:onClick="loadConstraintLayout"       #<-----Here it is.
            android:text="LOAD"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
```

What can possibly be the problem?

Comment: maybe it needs public void???

Answer (score 0):

Just add public modifier to your method.

Answer (score -1):

Your methods will need to be set to public void. This is important in OOP languages as your function cannot be called outside of the class now.

Comment: Yes I changed it and it works. The strange part is that the tutorial I found it from, had it like the code above. Non public.

Comment: That's strange, as Void is only the return type and gives no access to other functions which access modifiers do as I know of..

Comment: This is wrong, you can call protected methods within the same java package and all child classes. Even the official [Android Specification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) says that the method is protected by default.